# JSON parse emoji unicode crashing my react native project

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, unicode, expo

Whenever I try to display some data fetched in my React Native project from my API endpoint I get this JSON parse error: `JSON parse error on line 0 near .."}], [18933, "RC': expected another Unicode escape for the second half of surrogate pair`

Clearly, there is a missing escape character for Unicode escape symbol.

My string is 
"You can try, but I don’t think so "

I tried printing the string in the console and it displays fine, but when I try to display it in React Native's `<Text></Text>` component my app crashes.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You should answer your question in the space below and keep the question/answer separated.

Comment: got it, will do

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATE***

I found that the problem was with the JavaScript `String.substring()` method. It does not know how to properly split unicode surrogate pairs and therefore will try to split the string in the middle of a pair if you're unlucky with the positioning.

I solved the problem by using a library called "runes" that properly splits and takes a substring of a string with unicode surrogate pairs honored.

Problem: 
`postComment.substring(0, 35)`
Solution: `runes.substr(postComment, 0, 35)`

Simply install the `runes` library and use `runes.substr(yourString, start, end)` to handle unicode surrogate pairs in your string :)

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This is more of a guess since I only have your error and the  emoji to work with.

The unicode character for 'FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY' is (`U+1F602`) and the surrogate pair is `\uD83D\uDE02`.

If you input `\uD83D\uDE02` in the text component and that works, then you can convert using

```
function findSurrogatePair(point) {
  // assumes point > 0xffff
  var offset = point - 0x10000,
      lead = 0xd800 + (offset >> 10),
      trail = 0xdc00 + (offset & 0x3ff);
  return [lead.toString(16), trail.toString(16)];
}

// find pair for U+1F602
findSurrogatePair(0x1f602); // ["d83d", "de02"]
```

Reference + credit: http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript

**Disclaimer**: this is more of a guess since I only have your error and the  emoji to work with.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. The problem was that javascript doesn't properly handle splitting a string with Unicode characters that are represented with a surrogate pair. What happened was that the original string was, "You can try, but I don’t think so ", and when I tried to execute postComment.substring(0, 35) it sliced the string in the middle of a surrogate pair.  I fixed this by using a library called "runes" to easily take a substring, with Unicode surrogate pairs handled and not sliced in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

If your emoji unicode like `\uD83D\uDE02` format this javascript function convert unicode to emoji

```
    var unicodeToChar = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/\\u[\dA-F]{4}/gi, function(match) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match.replace(/\\u/g, ''), 16));
  });
}
```